# Vector arrows over flow velocity map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, vector-layer

I have a point layer with `X`, `Y`, `Vel` and `VelA` parameters where `Vel` stands for the magnitude of flow velocity and the `VelA` is a rotation of the arrows so the arrow is pointing on the dominant direction of flow in given area. This point layer is above a raster layer which shows the velocities at color range.

When I go to Layer styling of the point layer and select Size to be the `Vel` and Rotation to be the `VelA` the result is somewhat strange - see attached picture. The very same picture is in every point of the point layer - for ilustration I am attaching a larger cut from the map where the points arranged in grid can be seen. When I zoom to the specific one point I see the situation on the second picture.

[image: Picture one]My aim is to have a single point on map represented by the arrow which size and rotation is given by the attributes.

Any ideas where the problem might be?

[image: Picture two]

Comment: Solution 1 : your map has a very low scale so all the points are aggregated. Solution 2 : there is on one map point many points at the same place, which overlap.

Comment: Please add more details on your symbology.

Comment: The velocity is too large for array size. Use expression e.g. Vel / 10.

Comment: @J.Monticolo My map seems to have normal scale as I exported several maps already and they are fine. It seems the scale of the point layer is strange. Is there a way how I can change it?

Comment: @Erik I've attached Picture one where are some details.

Comment: @Zoltan the size is ranging from 0,003 to 2,48. I think it has more to do with the size characteristic (milimeters/pixels/map units etc.)

Comment: @Petr: use the Identify features tool for click in one map point, for example on your second zoomed map example to see how much feature points are in.

Comment: Then there are overlapping points as @Monticolo supposed. Try to select by rectangle a point. How many selected points are in the table?

Answer (score 1):

@Zoltan @JMonticolo Thank you for clues, I found out where the problem was. Truly one point was covering over 1200 features and it was because of joining attributes by nearest and then the XY left the same while I needed to use the new XY of nearest feature. Thats why one single point was covering all the points in the layer.